# How to get My Site Information from 2 differents Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010, mysite

I've got 2 distinct sharepoint. One 2007 and the other 2010.

On the 2010, there are MySite profile enabled.

I'm looking for a webpart OutOfBox (because my administrator doesn't allow to add new webpart in the curren t sharepoint) to access from SP 2007 to the information (like status, or project assignment) on MySite on SP 2010.

Are you thinking it's possible?

Thanks in advance

Julien Garcia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't think much can be done using OOTB webparts you have to for a custom webpart solution